# Pycharm cell mode .show() can run only 1 time

Tags: matplotlib, pycharm

I am using pycharm pro cell mode. I want to plot interactive graphs with matplotlib and disabled showing plots in the tool window option. When I run the cell with .show() it shows the graph in a window, just as I want it to do. But when I run the same cell second time, it does not plot the graph.

After running the cell for first time the displayed message is : "Backend MacOSX is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on."